# Allow user to decided columns to view in DevExpress GridControl

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

This is more of a design related query rather that implementation one. I have 4 columns in a DevExpress GridControl. As due to lack of space in my window, I have decided to show only 1 column and hide the rest 3 by default during initial windows load, further I want to provide the user with the ability to view/add hidden columns if more information is needed. My question is, is there a elegant way to solve this problem.

Proposed solutions from my end:

1. Have a radio buttons on top of grid having "Compact" or "Detailed" options, on selection of respective radio choices, hide or display optional columns at runtime.
2. Hide the optional columns permanently, and display the data present in the optional columns as a tooltip for each row in first columns.

I am somehow not satisfied with above mentioned approaches. Please help me get a neat approach to achieve the same.

Thanks
Siddharth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DevExpress WPF GridControl already has that functionality built-in. There is a [Column Chooser](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument6154) feature which allows the end user to select which columns to show in the grid:

[image]

more information on: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument6154

Comment: Thanks HighCore, I believe this is an elegant way of handling the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You should better put a horizontal scroll bar. This will solve all your problem. You will be able to show all the columns at the same time. If user wants to see additional columns, he will scroll horizontally.

You can **GridViewSettings.Settings.ShowHorizontalScrollBar** property to **"true".**

This devX [support ticket](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A362) may help you in detail.